# How can i Check JavascriptExecutor in loop?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to exit loop if the string give an error, I cant check if it's null.

The loop take 2 scripts and take all the cells, in the end the compiler give an error.

How i can exit before calculating the last string(the error time) ?

Thanks

```
String script3 = "return document.getElementsByTagName('g')[" + f9 + "].textContent";
n = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script3, hiddenDiv);
```

`n` takes all the tags(g), at the end it's give an error not null, so i cant stop the loop.

I want to stop the loop before the error.

I do this to count the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `try` `catch` for catching the error and breaking the loop

```
for(...)
{
   try
   {
      //your javascript code HERE
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      string exMessage = getMessage();
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: what we write inside the catch ?

Comment: from ex you can get all the information about the exception

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the `g` tags using `findElements` method

```
List<WebElement> gTags = driver.findElements(By.tagName("g"));
```

And to get the number of `g` tags

```
int size = gTags.size();
```

Comment: But, the g tags inside hidden element.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. I would do it like the below. Basically you use Javascript to grab all the `g` tags, loop through them collecting their `.textContent`, and then return that `List` to your Java code. You can then loop through the `List` in Java and do whatever.

```
String script3 = "var strings = []; var g = document.getElementsByTagName('g'); for (var i = 0; i < g.length; i++) { strings.push(g[i].textContent); } return strings;";
List<String> s = (List<String>) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script3);
System.out.println(s);
```